# How to keep a strong reference in Go?

Tags: arrays, pointers, go, slice

Is there any way I can keep a strong reference in Go?

Given the following convoluted piece of code:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func main() {   
  slice := make([]int, 5)
  slice[3] = 25 // whatever index between 0 and 4 included I don't care

  slicesArray := make([]*[]int, 2)  
  slicesArray[0] = &slice

  fmt.Println((*(slicesArray[0]))[3])
  slice = nil
  fmt.Println((*(slicesArray[0]))[3])
}
```

This program of course crashes because once setting the **slice** to `nil` the garbage collector marks the memory area as dirty.

But is there a way to tell Go that my slice of pointers to slices should keep a strong reference to those slices? 
Also, is there any memory usage gain in keeping references to slices rather than declaring slicesArray as `[][]int`? Is there any doc clearly stating how this is supposed to work?

Comment: "because once setting the slice to nil the garbage collector marks the memory area as dirty" this is incorrect. If any code has a pointer to something then the garbage collector leaves it alone. You can set pointers to `nil` all day long and nothing happens with the garbage collector (**unless** what *was* pointed to is now no longer pointed to by anything else).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR:** (summary)

You just need to make a copy of the slice value. A value of slice type is a descriptor to an *underlying* array:

```
slice2 := slice
```

Now `slice2` will refer to the same, shared underlying array and so it will be reachable after `slice` is zerored.

**In long:**

```
slice := make([]int, 5)
```

This creates a local variable named `slice` of type `[]int` (and will be initialized with a descriptor referring to an array of size `5` created in the background by `make`). It's a slice which is a descriptor to a contiguous part of an underlying array which is created automatically in the background.

```
slicesArray[0] = &slice
```

This stores the address of the local variable (named `slice`) into the 0th element of `slicesArray`. Note that `slicesArray` is just a slice of pointers (which pointers may point to values of type `[]int` but that doesn't matter now).

So still no copy of the original `slice` is created.

And so when you zero the only value of type `[]int` (which is the local variable named `slice`), you zero the only slice value (and you'll lose the only reference to its backing array).

You want to keep the slice value after `slice` has been zeroed? Just make a copy of it (of the slice value). Copying a value of slice type only makes a copy of the descriptor, the backing array is not copied; and the copy will refer to the same backing array (it's shared):

```
slice2 := slice // makes a copy of the slice value
slice = nil
```

After this `*(slicesArray[0])` will still point to a slice value being `nil`, but we have a copy of the original slice (and the shared backing array).

So doing:

```
slicesArray[0] = &slice2
fmt.Println((*(slicesArray[0]))[3])
```

Will print again `25`. [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/jHGpg0Kxwn)

**Should you keep slice values or pointers to slices?**

Since slices are just descriptors which are relatively small, you should keep and work with slice values. A slice value already contains a "reference" to a backing array. Adding another indirection by using a pointer to a slice just complicates and slightly slows things down. A slice is already designed to be small, efficient and flexible (compared to "real" arrays in Go).

Of course a pointer to a slice value may also be useful in some cases, for example if you would ever want to create a function similar to the builtin [`append()`](http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) function without returning the new slice. Or when you create a custom type whose underlying type is a slice type, and you define methods for this type which modify the slice value (in this case a pointer receiver is necessary).

**Further readings:** (the docs explaining everything in detail)

[Go Slices: usage and internals](http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals)

[Arrays, slices (and strings): The mechanics of 'append'](http://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: So is the builtin `copy` function (or `:=` operator, whatever) using a COW approach? I mean, is the memory only allocated once for the slice holding the integer of value 3?

Comment: Or, better yet: is this example using the same amount of memory as yours?   http://play.golang.org/p/e_ELjfseCO

Comment: @alediaferia An array can hold elements. A slice is just a descriptor, it refers to an underlying array. In the example(s) only one backing array is allocated (by this: `make([]int, 5)`). You can have as many slices refering to the same array as you want, only the slice descriptor will be "duplicated" in memory.

Comment: @alediaferia a slice is a reference type.

Comment: Alright. Thanks everybody. You all helped me getting this straight.

Comment: @alediaferia In your second example (linked in your comment), also only one backing array of type `[]int` is created, and when you do this: `slicesArray[0] = slice` (where `slicesArray` is of type `[][]int`), the slice value, the descriptor is copied to the 0th element of `slicesArray`. The backing array of `slice` is not copied or duplicated, just the slice value is copied.